# Replace Line Breaks (Multiple count as 1) in a string

Tags: apex, string, regular-expressions, line-break

Given a string with the following variations where {br} is a line break not a literal

1. Line 1{br}Line 2
2. Line 1{br}{br}Line2
3. Line 1{br}{br}{br}Line 2{br}

Basically any number of line breaks between lines.

Trying to find the regex that will replace all Single and multiple occurrences (treated as one) with the characters **

Result should be

> Line 1 ** Line 2

In all cases from above.

Right now I have this as a solution but I am sure the brains here have a better, smaller, easier way:

```
String testString = 'Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\n\r\nLine 3';
String[] tmp = testString.split('\\r|\\n');

for(integer x=0;x<tmp.size();x++){
    if(tmp[x].isWhitespace()){
        tmp.remove(x);
        x--;
    }
}

System.debug(String.join(tmp,' ** '));
```

Results

> Line 1 ** Line 2 ** Line 3

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a good time for `replaceAll(regex, replacement)`:

```
String testString = 'Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\n\r\nLine 3';
system.debug(testString.replaceAll('(\\r|\\n)+', ' ** '));
```

Results:

> Line 1 ** Line 2 ** Line 3

Comment: Aww dang it. I was not using the `+` and it was causing `Line 2 ** ** Line 3`. Stupid mistake. Thanks